# Making a section change by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am making a website under react with reactstrap, i have a section that contains charts and a button whose function is to replace said charts with another chart containing more details. however i am struggling to make a concrete code.

i have tried placing the charts in a separate component and have it's content switch through the use of a handleclick function on the button that changes the state of the section (using 'onclick')

i am really not confident in my code's clarity, so i tried reproducing what i did in a simpler matter within fiddle

```
class hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
          <h2>hello</h2>
    );
    }
}

class bye extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
          <h2>goodbye</h2>
    );
    }
}

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.components[hello]}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          switch
          {this.setState({components:[<bye />]})}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

the div in the "toggle" component is supposed to switch between the components "hello" and "bye"

in effect the current section that is supposed to be displayed ("hello") will be replaced by the other section ("bye") uppon clicking the button under them.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your App `state` does not have any `component` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to toggle between the two components with the button click, you can use conditional rendering.
Change your `render` method to this:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.isToggleOn?<Hello />:<Bye />}
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Switch</button>
        </div>
 }
```

Also keep your Component's name first character capitalized or react might complain. And using `Class` based Components is outdated. `Hooks` are the hot thing right now. So try to use more `Functional` Components.

Note: My answer assumes you are using `babel presets` for transpiling `jsx` and `es6` syntax. If not, check out @Colin's answer. It also uses hooks.

Comment: you assumed right!
i have a new problem however, one of my toggling components is dependent to the main component (the "toggle" in my example), it needs to be a const in my main component since it uses some of it's data, how should the toggler work then?

Answer (score 1):

why not import all partial views and conditionally render them based on the condition

```
{condition & <View1/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few mistakes in your code. Here's an example which does what you want using conditional rendering:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Hello = () => {
  return <h2>hello</h2>;
};

const Bye = () => {
  return <h2>bye</h2>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggled(!toggled);
  };

  const render = () => {
    if (toggled) {
      return <Hello />;
    }

    return <Bye />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>toggle</button>
      {render()}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit elated-margulis-ubxq2]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it:

1. Using conditional operator:

```js
{ this.state.isToggleOn?<Hello/>:<Bye/>  }
```

2. Using if condition:

```js
render() {

  let chart;

  if(this.state.isToggleOn) {
   chart = <Hello/>;
  } else {
   chart = <Bye/>;
  }

  return ( <div> {  chart } </div>);
}
```

3 You can use switch case also for conditional rendering. Here it is not well suited as condition is true or false.